# Hover shows lower div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I Want to show a div with a background color and inside it a `<p>` with a title. In hover over it a `<p>` (text) should be appear and the first one dissapears(title). I was playing with z-index property but I can´t achieve it:

This is my code:

```css
.magigDiv {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px double black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
}

.text1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="magigDiv">
  <p class="text1" style="width: 100%;z-index:100;height:150px;position:absolute;">
    LOREM IPSUM
  </p>
  <p style="z-index: -1;width: 100%; height:150px;position:absolute;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something simple with setting `opacity` 0 to 1. check below snippet for reference.

```css
.magigDiv {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px double black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;  
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.text {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.title:hover+.text {
  opacity: 1;
}
.title:hover{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="magigDiv">
  <p class="title">
    LOREM IPSUM
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing... It works!! Thanks @RaJeshRiJo. One question more, what is .title:hover+.text ?

Comment: `.title` and `.text` are siblings, so here `+` helps to find the adjacent sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css first:

```
div p:last-child:hover { top:-50px; position:relative; background-color:green;}
```

And change few properties in inline style you applied like following:

```
<div style="width: 40%; float:left; background-color: green;padding: 10px; position:relative;">

    <p style="z-index: 2;width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:100; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        LA EMPRESA
    </p>
    <p style="z-index: 3;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
        sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hanif. Now I can see the two <p> and in hover the second one cover the first out of the original div

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to:

1) assign a fixed height to `<div>`

2) use `position: relative` for `<div>` and `position: absolute` for both `<p>`

3) you need to use JQuery to slide up first `<p>` so that the second one is shown

Comment: How can I get it using Jquery?